# How to do the sum for each row of the values of a column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, sum

I have a SQL table containing a column of list of int, like this

```
Index   Column to sum
1   1:5:13:3:6:7:11:2:4:1:2:5
2   1:7:2:1:1
3   19:05:05
4   2:1:1:5:1:4:64:177:86:75:2:83:2:57:1
5   43
6   1:1:1:3:10:6:1
7   2:11:4:3:1
8   1:5:2:3:34:2:2
9   4:3:1:2
10  4:1:1:4
```

I would like to calcul in SQL the sum for each row of the *Column to sum* value.
It would give something like this:

```
1 60
2 12
...
10 10
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? the syntax may differ between MySql, SQL server, Postgres and others

Comment: Why do you have such a broken data model?  Numbers should not be stored as strings, and columns should have just one value.  The values should be stored in a table with one value per row.

Comment: @gbalduzzi You are right, I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: @GordonLinoff Data does not come from me unfortunatly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first effort should go into fixing your data model, as commented by Gordon Linoff. The numbers should be stored in a separate table, with each value on a separate row.

In Postgres, you can split the values to rows using `regexp_split_to_table()`, then aggregate:

```
select t.id, sum(x.val::int) result
from mytable t
cross join lateral regexp_split_to_table(t.column_to_sum, ':') as x(val)
group by t.id
```